# Find all ID's in 2 different tables that Don't have a Username

Tags: sql, sqlite

Ok, so I have two tables. Table1 and Table2.

```
Table1 - All ID's
ID

Table2 - All ID's with Usernames
ID
Username
```

I want to select all ID's that DON'T have usernames. Table2 only has ID's that have Usernames. Basically I want to do a select on table 1 join 2 table on ID that don't have usernames. Since table2 only has ID's with usernames, it's basically all of the ID's that are in Table 2 subtracted from the TOTAL ID's in table1 so that I only get ID's that aren't in table2 but are in table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select id from table1
left join table2 on table2.id = table1.id 
where table2.usernames is null
```

or you can do a `not in`

```
select id from table1 where id not in(select id from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t1.ID 
FROM Table1 t1 
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON
        t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t2.Usernames IS NULL
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is with a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT id FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT id FROM Table2;
```